# Pine Script: Colour specific 5 minute candles if they are bullish or bearish

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to colour the 5 minute candles at xx:05 and xx:35 red if they are bullish and green if they are bearish (ie. 12:05 green, 12:35 red, 13:05 green etc)

Thanks to @vitruvius I was able to color the respective candles with the code below:

```
//@version=5 indicator("05", overlay=true)


first_candle = minute(time) == 05  
second_candle = minute(time) == 35 

barcolor(first_candle ? color.green : na, title="05")
 
barcolor(second_candle ? color.yellow : na, title="35")
```

The Screenshot below shows that the xx:05er are coloured green and the xx:35er are coloured yellow.

However, I want to differentiate between Bullish and Bearish candles. I assume I would need an Array, but I am kind of lost on how to store the respective values and perform the function which calculates if Bullish or Bearish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an array. A bullish candle is `close > open`. Check this condition together with the candle time and then set your color accordingly.

```
//@version=5 
indicator("05", overlay=true)

is_bullish = close > open
is_bearish = not is_bullish

first_candle = minute(time) == 05
second_candle = minute(time) == 35

color_05 = first_candle and is_bullish ? color.green : first_candle and is_bearish ? color.yellow : na
color_15 = second_candle and is_bullish ? color.green : second_candle and is_bearish ? color.yellow : na

barcolor(first_candle ? color.green : na, title="05")
barcolor(second_candle ? color.yellow : na, title="35")
```

Comment: Damn that was easy

Thank you so much und Grüße nach München!